# unable to instanciate java methode with karate

Tags: javascript, java, api, types, karate

Method fails :

js failed: >>>> 01: WireMockHelper.get().reset() <<<< org.graalvm.polyglot.PolyglotException - logs.dependencies.utils.WireMockHelper.<init>(WireMockHelper.java:34) - logs.dependencies.utils.WireMockHelper.get(WireMockHelper.java:49) - <js>.:program(Unnamed:1)

i tried this :

```
    * def WireMockHelper = Java.type('logs.dependencies.utils.WireMockHelper')
    * def WireMockHelper_reset = WireMockHelper.get().reset()
```

Comment: clearly your java classpath is not set, please refer linked answer. if still stuck, follow this process: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue